# В InteliJ Idea не генерируются id в R.java

Tags: android, java, intellij-idea

Я недавно перешел на InteliJ Idea 12.

Сегодня создал проект на андроид и сразу столкнулся с проблемой: не генерируются id в R.java
Ребилд проекта не помогает.

Может в InteliJ Idea есть какие-то тонкости не известные мне?

Ошибка:

```
12-01 16:08:15.067: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:266)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3624)
    at com.example.poem_new.MyActivity.invalidateCounters(MyActivity.java:41)
    at com.example.poem_new.MyActivity.access$000(MyActivity.java:11)
    at com.example.poem_new.MyActivity$1.onTextChanged(MyActivity.java:29)
    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8027)
    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:8074)
    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:8454)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:892)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:266)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:443)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:420)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:29)
    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:669)
    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:188)
    at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:149)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:315)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:85)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Файл R.java пуст:

```
 /* This stub is for using by IDE only. It is NOT the R class actually packed into APK */
public final class R {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1'
```

Это означает, что компилятор ресурсов не смог найти строковый идентификатор в каком-то вашем ресурсе.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте правильность имен в ресурсах. Например могут начинаться с цифры знака и тп.